# fopen() with r+ acts like a?

Tags: php, fopen

This is some of the weirdest stuff I've ever honestly seen.

```
$filename = "/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r+");
$size = filesize($filename);
$contents = fread($handle, $size);
fwrite($handle,$contents);
fclose($handle);
```

Shouldn't this read the contents of the file then write it again? Basically leaving the file unmodified? At this moment this piece of code does exactly what append does, it duplicates the contents of the file adding $contents at the end of the file, and I have no idea why. I tried changing the string a little before writing it and that's how I found out it writes to the end, not the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `fread()` is advancing the file pointer such that by the time you call `fwrite`, your file pointer is at the end and your write appends to the file from there.

If you want to write to the file starting at the beginning after reading it all in then:

```
rewind($handle);
```

Comment: I had one more minute before I could